# How to add integers to a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, int

I'm trying to create a sorting algorithm based off a query. Essentially the user would input values for Height, Weight, and a few other attributes. I am then querying our database of models to match that person with someone who has the closest measurements to those that the user inputted. I'm trying to do this based off a weighted variable that I am assigning within the "while" statement of the query and then returning that variable's value at the end. Here is some code to show you what I mean:

```
$userHeight=$_POST['height'];
$userWeight=$_POST['weight'];
$userShoulder=$_POST['shoulder'];
$userWaist=$_POST['waist'];
$userInseam=$_POST['inseam'];

$heightMatchMultiple=0;
$heightMatchMultiple=0;
$weightMatchMultiple=0;
$shoulderMatchMultiple=0;
$waistMatchMultiple=0;
$inseamMatchMultiple=0;

function matchValues($array){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($array) > 0) {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($array)){
                $heightMatchMultiple=0;

                if(isset($row['modelHeight'])){
                    if($userHeight==$row['modelHeight']){
                        $heightMatchMultiple=10;
                    }
                    elseif($userHeight==$row['modelHeight']+1 || $userHeight==$row['modelHeight']-1){
                        $heightMatchMultiple=9;
                    }
                    elseif($userHeight==$row['modelHeight']+2 || $userHeight==$row['modelHeight']-2){
                        $heightMatchMultiple=8;
                    }
                    elseif($userHeight==$row['modelHeight']+3 || $userHeight==$row['modelHeight']-3){
                        $heightMatchMultiple=7;
                    }
                    else{
                        $heightMatchMultiple=1;
                    }
                }

                echo "Model Match Multiple: " . $heightMatchMultiple . "<br>";
            }
        }//end of if num rows 
        else {
            echo "No results to display.";
        }
    }//end of function
```

When I run this function, it is returning the else statement's value for heightMatchMultiple of 1 instead of 10 because there is a model in the database with a height of 69 which is what I used as user input.

Can I add +1 or +2 directly to the $row['modelHeight'] variable as I did or is there a better way to do this.

EDIT:
Some people were asking where I initialized the variable $userHeight so i added it to the code. I tried creating global variables for $heightMatchMultiple=0 as a way to make those variables usable within my matchValues function. Is this correct?

Comment: Should work as is, I'd parenthesize the math bit, `($row['modelHeight']+1)` though so it is easier to read though. https://eval.in/474837 Are you having some issue or error?

Comment: From where do you get the value of `$userHeight`? Your logic is inside a function and seems `$userHeight` is outside the function. So in this case `$userHeight` value is blank and hence it will always go into `ELSE` condition.

Comment: Thanks, I just made an edit to show the code from where I am getting $userHeight. Does this explain why I might be getting the else value of 1?

Comment: I think that is JS syntax/scope you are thinking of, that won't work in PHP. Variables aren't available to PHP functions unless passed in or given to global scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php Also unrelated but `$array` isn't a very descriptive variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `$userHeight` being initialized/passed in? I think the reason you're currently getting 69 is because `$userHeight` has not been set, hence it gets a value of zero by default, which means that 1 will be the correct answer if `$row['modelHeight']` is 69.

To answer your real question, which is really about order of operations: yes, what you have written should do what I believe you are trying to achieve. However, you should probably add parenthesis, even though they aren't strictly necessary, just as a hint to your future self that you really did intend for the calculations to happen in a certain order.

For example, instead of this:

```
elseif($userHeight == $row[ 'modelHeight' ] + 1 || $userHeight == $row[ 'modelHeight' ] - 1)
```

you could write this:

```
elseif(($userHeight == ( $row[ 'modelHeight' ] + 1 )) || ( $userHeight == ( $row[ 'modelHeight' ] - 1)))
```

Or you could re-write each of the checks using `abs()` like this:

```
elseif(abs($userHeight - $row['modelHeight']) == 1 )
```

This is arguably more descriptive, since what you're really trying to say is "if the difference is 1".

But yes, you can use the + 1 and +2 etc as in your original code, but you do need to set or pass in the `$userHeight` variable at some point.